# Pen-input digitizer for DIY E-Ink Graphics Tablet

Tags: graphics-tablet, e-ink

I want to build an E-Ink Graphics Tablet. My plan is to:

1. Lay the E-Ink display on top of a pen input digitizer.
2. The E-Ink display would be driven using FPGA as instructed [here](https://hackaday.com/2017/04/20/e-ink-display-driven-diy/).
3. The pen input digitizer would record the strokes and send it to the E-ink display.

I need information on where I can find some hardware that can digitize pen strokes. I found some useful information about the pen input digitizers:

1. Information about the format of input one expects to get from the pen input digitizers and illustration of some difficulties one may face in making these devices work with Linux machines: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nPab7pbOhBY) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j4AKwJERxOw)
2. Names of some pen input devices- Pen input system antenna (BTM-P097), Waltop WA2006 Pen-Input Technology IC module, Waltop MCU1086 A3A5A from [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/cracking-open/boogie-board-rip-teardown-overpriced-and-a-few-features-short/)

However I am unable to find any hardware that I can order for the pen-input digitizer. (I wouldn't want to pluck out parts of an existing product, unless you say that is indeed the best way to go about it). Would you name me some suitable components if you know of any?

I have found some E-ink displays that I can order from the [E Ink Shop](https://shopkits.eink.com/). But I would also be happy to hear of any alternatives that you may have to suggest.

My priority order for the hardware is as follows:
1. easily available documentation
2. easy to work with
3. easy on the wallet